# Yosemite keyboard shortcut for "keep both" "stop" or "replace" when moving files in Finder?

Tags: keyboard, macos, finder, copy-paste

When you **copy or move files in the Finder** in Yosemite and there is a conflict, a small dialog box pops up proposing:

```
keep both    stop    replace
```

(or "skip" if you press option).

**However, I can't find any way to choose one of the options with the keyboard.**

There's no default option. Cmd-R doesn't work for replace. Escape does nothing.

I've tried **every combination I can think of** and nothing works.

**Are there keyboard shortcuts to choose these options?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enable keyboard control in **Preferences**

[image]

With this, You can switch between buttons with <kbd>⇥ TAB</kbd> and select it with Space. Active button will have blue border.

NOTE: default buttons (all blue) are still clickable with <kbd>⏎ RETURN</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, that works great. I will be curious to see if the extra functionality is annoying elsewhere (on web pages for example).

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know about that. Took me a sec to realize even the "apply to all button" is included in this